# Not found my web-page showing HTTP 404 error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, http

The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

I have tried every thing and I couldn't able to solve it.

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>telusko</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  
  
</web-app>
```

controller code

```
  package tusky;


  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

  @Controller 
  public class IndexController  {

     @RequestMapping("/")
     public String home() {
    
         return "index.jsp";
     }

     @RequestMapping("/feedback.htm")
     public String feedback()
    {
        return "feedback.jsp";
    }
  }
```

please let me know what's the issue

Comment: Your context is telusko which port are you using? Also can you share your controller?

Comment: here is the url- http://localhost:8080/tusky/ and

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:{PORT}/telusko/{your_path}
```

For more information you have to share your controller and your path

You are not using spring boot so your web.xml redirects to spring dispatcherservlet. Your context is important you can specify it in web.xml